# Find list of words in a dataframe string column

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have a dataframe column which contains names of articles(name: Article). I am looking to create another column which scans each element of the Article column and find presence of any of the following keywords from the list:

```
['What','Why','How', 'Who', 'COVID-19', 'COVID', 'When','Where','?']
```

Issue is the presence of '?' returns a *error: nothing to repeat at position 32*. I tried passing regex= False to my code still see the same issue

```
mylist = ['What','Why','How', 'Who', 'COVID-19', 'COVID', 'When','Where','?']
pattern = '|'.join(mylist)
df1_pcp['Boolean flag'] = df1_pcp.Title.str.contains(pattern)
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: `'?'` is a special regex character, consider replace it with `'\?'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the strings that need to retain literal (non-RE) semantics within the regular expression. You can automatically escape the string using `re.escape()` from the `re` library:

```
import re

mylist = ['What','Why','How', 'Who', 'COVID-19', 'COVID', 'When','Where','?']

print('|'.join(mylist))

pattern = '|'.join(re.escape(elem) for elem in mylist)
print(pattern)
```

Observe the output:

```
What|Why|How|Who|COVID-19|COVID|When|Where|?
What|Why|How|Who|COVID\-19|COVID|When|Where|\?
```

As you can see, the pattern where we escaped your literal strings, the hyphen
and the ? characters got escapes. PCRE patterns don't assign special "metacharacter" meaning to
hyphen except within character classes -- at least not that I can recall, but it also doesn't hurt anything to escape that character.

It's usually a good idea to `re.escape` strings that you intend to pass into
a regular expression engine, unless you explicitly with to retain their 'pattern'
qualities as opposed to their literal string characteristics. This is particularly
true if your search terms come from external sources that may now have an understanding of regular expressions, or worse, do have, and use their understanding to craft an abysmally pessimal regex.